# C# Entity To Linq Expression error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I don't understand why I get this error:

*'variable 'c' of type 'SomeEntity' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined'.*

This is the code that i'm trying to execute. 
It seems like it's complaining about the parameter value c.Id that i pass to the IsNicePredicate method, but I can't seem to understand why.

```
    var result =  _dbContext.Set<SomeEntity>().Select(c => new SomeEntityDto
    {
        BlahBlah = c.BlahBlah,
        Hello = _dbContext.Set<Entity>().Where(IsNicePredicate(c.Id)).ToList(),
        XXX = c.XXX,
        YYY = c.YYY
    });


    private Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> IsNicePredicate(int collateralId)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        return e => e.AnotherEntity.Any(x => x.Good && x.Bye == collateralId);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

EF is going to translate your code to SQL. So the lambda as the body of the `Select` isn't executed directly, rather interpreted and translated.

I think you either need to use LINQKit or try manually putting the body of `IsNicePredicate` in the query and see if that works.

I think you would need to use it as so:

```
var result =  _dbContext.Set<SomeEntity>().AsExpandable().Select(c => new SomeEntityDto
    {
        BlahBlah = c.BlahBlah,
        Hello = _dbContext.Set<Entity>().Where(IsNicePredicate(c.Id)).ToList(),
        XXX = c.XXX,
        YYY = c.YYY
    });
```

Since you are nesting a separate query, I am not sure if you need another `AsExpandable()`:

```
Hello = _dbContext.Set<Entity>().AsExpandable().Where(IsNicePredicate(c.Id)).ToList()
```

Comment: I don't want to place the IsNicePredicate method inside. I'm aware of how linq works, I just don't understand why it's loosing the context.

Comment: @MasterOfPuppets Then I guess you also know how to look at exception stack trace. I suspect it's a result of unexpected (missed) case (bug?) in some internal EF expression visitor implementation. But is it important at all? You can't use it this way, you really need to take the answerer advice and utilize LINQKit `AsExpandable` / `Invoke` or similar.

Comment: Can you at least provide solution with LINQKit  as I'm not familiar with it's API...

Comment: LINQKit is all nicely documented here http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work - I get the same error message.

Comment: Have you tried expanding `IsNicePredicate` manually to verify the cause of the error?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this?

```
 var result =  _dbContext.Set<SomeEntity>()
    .Select(c => new { c, Hello = _dbContext.Set<Entity>().Where(e => e.AnotherEntity.Any(x => x.Good && x.Bye == c.Id)).ToList() })
    .Select(ch => new SomeEntityDto
    {
        BlahBlah = ch.c.BlahBlah,
        Hello = ch.Hello,
        XXX = ch.c.XXX,
        YYY = ch.c.YYY
    });
```